# Catching the "Pixel outside the boundaries" exception?

Tags: exception, pixel, dm-script

I have an image with atoms that are periodically arranged.

I am trying to write a script that does count how many atoms are arranged in first column by assigning a ROI on top-left atom, then let the script to *scan* from left to right (column by column). My idea is that, by using ROI that *scans* from left to right, and when it *hits* pixel that is out of boundaries (which means, it is out of image), the script returns the number of atoms in one line, instead of giving an error output saying "A pixel outside the boundaries of the image has been referenced".

Is there any way to make the above case possible to write in script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *catch* any exception thrown by the script-code to handle it yourself using the

```
Try(){ }
Catch{ break; }
```

construct. However, this is not the nicest solution for your problem. If you *know* the size of your image, your really rather should use that knowledge to prevent accessing data outside the bonds. Using `Try{}Catch{}` is better left to those situation where *"anything unexpected"* could happen, and you still want to handle the problem.

Here is a code example for your question.

```
number boxSize = 3

number sx = 10
number sy = 10
image img := realImage( "Test", 4, sx, sy )
img = random()

// Output "sum" over scanned ROI area

// Variant 1: Just scan -- Hits an exception, as you're moving out of range
/*
for( number j=0;j<sy;j++)
    for( number i=0;i<sx;i++)
        {
            Result("\n ScanPos: " + i +" / " + j )
            Result("\t SUM: "+ sum( img[j,i,j+boxSize,i+boxSize] ) );
        }
*/

// Variant 2: As above, but catch exception to just continue
for( number j=0;j<sy;j++)
    for( number i=0;i<sx;i++)
        {
            Result("\n ScanPos: " + i +" / " + j )
            Try
            {
                Result( "\t SUM: "+ sum( img[j,i,j+boxSize,i+boxSize] ) );
            }
            catch
            {
                Result( "\t ROI OUT OF RANGE" )
                break;      // Needed in scripting, or the exception is re-thrown
            }
        }

// Variant 3: (Better) Avoid hitting the exception by using the knowlede of data size
for( number j=0;j<sy-boxSize;j++)
    for( number i=0;i<sx-boxSize;i++)
        {
            Result("\n ScanPos: " + i +" / " + j )
            Result("\t SUM: "+ sum( img[j,i,j+boxSize,i+boxSize] ) );
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! There is one thing I am not quite understand. What does it mean by "the exception is *re-thrown*"? @BmyGuest

Comment: Essentially, any code (C++) can run into some "unexpected" troubles. (Say a division through zero or anything.) At such a moment, "an exception is thrown", bascially a message is sent "something is wrong". Another part of the code "catches" this and acts accordingly - f.e. prompting an error message. If *no* code catches an exception, the appliction might simply crash & close.  The "out of bonds" error is such a moment - you ask the programm to access some memory, which does not exist! Normally, the "script engine" catches this, and prompts the error. If you instead use "Try{}Catch{}", then...

Comment: ..you yourself can "handle" the situation as shown above. However, if you don't put the "break" in the catch-loop, then the orignal "exception" is not removed from the queue and the DM-script code is *still* prompting you with the error message. Just try out the code above without the "break".

Comment: Thank you! I did try the code above and I understand now what it means by *re-thrown*. But when I try the idea of Try-Catch in my script, it didn't go well. As I let a particular size of ROI *moves* atomic-column by atomic-column, and when it comes to the last atomic column which is located close to the side of the image (but not at the last pixel of the image), the script will still run and cause the ROI to end up outside of image. May I know how to deal with case above?

Comment: As an additional info, I do know the size of image but the *movement* of ROI is not fixed. Thus, when ROI is at the last atomic column; it is located not at the last pixel of the image. Instead of letting ROI to keep *moving* as there are some pixels *in front of* them, I try to make ROI to stop there at the last atomic column even though the last atomic column is not at the last pixel of the image. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @Aning This is not different to the example above. You know the *size* of the ROI (if it is user-drawn you can get it with 'GetSelection()' or some other commands as well). This is like the "boxsize" in my example. Iterate your for-loop until imageSize minus ROISize.

Comment: @Aning: I've added an example below.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the questions in the comments of the accepted answer:
You can query any ROI/Selection on an image and use this info to limit the iteration.
The following example shows this. It also shows how the ROI object is properly used, both to get the selection as well as to add new ROIs. More info is found in the F1 help:

[image]

The script takes the front-most image with exactly one selection on it.
It then iterates the selection from the top-left onward (in a given step-size ) and outputs the region's sum value. Finally, you can opt to draw the used areas as new ROIs.

[image]
[image]

```
ClearResults()

// 1) Get image and image size
image img := GetFrontImage()
number sx = img.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
number sy = img.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
Result( "Image size: "+ sx + "x"+ sy+"\n")

// 2) Get the size of the user-drawn selection (ROI)
//  2a)
//  If you are only dealing with the simple, user-drawn rectangle selections
//  you can use the simplified code below instead.
number t, l, b, r
img.GetSelection(t,l,b,r)
Result( "Marker coordinates (simple): ["+t+","+l+","+b+","+r+"]\n" )

//  2b)
//  Or you can use the "full" commands to catch other situations.
//  The following lines check ROIs in a more general way.
//  Not strictly needed, but to get you started if you want
//  to use the commands outlined in F1 help section 
//  "Scripting > Objects > Document Object Model > ROI Object"
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
if( 0 == disp.ImageDisplayCountROIs() )
    Throw( "No ROI on the image." )
if( 1 < disp.ImageDisplayCountROIs() )
    Throw( "More than one ROI on the image." )

ROI theMarker = disp.ImageDisplayGetROI(0)  // First (and only) ROI

if ( !theMarker.ROIIsRectangle() )
    Throw( "ROI not a rectangle selection." )

if ( !theMarker.ROIGetVolatile() )
    Throw( "ROI not voltaile." )            // Voltile = ROI disappears when another is drawn. Dashed outline.

number top, left, bottom, right
theMarker.ROIGetRectangle( top, left, bottom, right )
Result( "Marker coordinates (ROI commands): ["+top+","+left+","+bottom+","+right+"]\n" )

// 3) Iterate within bounds
number roiWidth  = right - left
number roiHeight = bottom - top

number roiXStep = 100   // We shift the ROI in bigger steps
number roiYStep = 100   // We shift the ROI in bigger steps
if ( !GetNumber( "The ROI is " + roiWidth + "pixels wide. Shift in X?", roiWidth, roiXStep ) )
    exit(0)
if ( !GetNumber( "The ROI is " + roiHeight + "pixels heigh. Shift in Y?", roiHeight, roiYStep ) )
    exit(0)

for ( number j = 0; j<sy-roiHeight; j+=roiYStep )
    for ( number i = 0; i<sx-roiWidth; i+=roiXStep )
    {
        Result( "Sum at "+i+"/"+j+": " + sum( img[j,i,j+roiHeight,i+roiWidth] ) + "\n" )
    }

// 4) If you want you can "show" the used positions.
if ( !TwoButtonDialog("Draw ROIs?","Yes","No") )
    exit(0)


for ( number j = 0; j<sy-roiHeight; j+=roiYStep )
    for ( number i = 0; i<sx-roiHeight; i+=roiXStep )
    {
        roi markerROI = NewRoi()
        markerROI.ROISetRectangle( j, i, j+roiHeight, i+roiWidth )
        markerROI.ROISetVolatile(0)
        markerROI.ROISetColor(0,0.4,0.4)
        markerROI.ROISetMoveable(0)
        markerROI.ROISetLabel( ""+i+"/"+j ) // Start with "" to ensure the parameter is recognized as string

        disp.ImageDisplayAddRoi( markerROI )
    }
```